# can't change the content of variable in file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file that has the variable in it like this :

destination=/usr/src/test

I want with the sed command, change the content of the destination variable to become like this :
destination=/etc/app

for this i used : ***sed -i 's/destination=.*/destination=/etc/app/' nameoffile***

but I had this mistake : sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'

any solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the regex separators.

Try changing your command as follow:

```
sed -i -r 's:destination=.*:destination=/etc/app:g' nameoffile
```